# Align checkbox center to label lines

Tags: css

I have a check-box and the label. If label is of two lines the check-box should be aligned in between two lines.
    
        
             Label text

Comment: what you have tried yet

Comment: Simplest way is to use html table. http://jsfiddle.net/oLnsr4rt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper display and vertical-align:

```css
label { display:inline-block; }
input { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
span { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>First<br>Second</span></label>
```